# Get value of AWT-Choice and convert to an Integer for AWT-Graphics method fillOval(x, y, int1, int2);

Tags: java, graphics, awt

```
x = e.getX();
y = e.getY();
-------------------------------
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
Graphics stift = getGraphics();
-------------------------------
**stift.fillOval(e.getX(), e.getY(), Integer.parseInt(freeSize.getSelectedItem(), Integer.parseInt(freeSize.getSelectedItem())));**
}
```

My problem in this code is that I have a Choice object where I can choose between sizes of the "stift" now I want the applet to put the String from the AWT-Choice into the parameters, logically it has to be parsed into an Integer.

Any ideas to solve the problem?

Comment: the ** aren't actually inside the code, it is just an indicator for where the problem is.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Why use AWT?   See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255106/java-gui-listeners-without-awt/6255978#6255978) for many good reasons to abandon AWT components in favor of Swing. 3) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).